# Cómo validar cada uno de los elementos de un array con Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Necesito validar que cada elemento del array sea único, lo recibo en el controlador pero no sé como validarlo, en el siguiente ejemplo no valida todos:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
    'serial' => ['required', 'unique:badges'],
]);
```

Se me ocurre esto, pero no sé como incluir el índice en el ciclo:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $c = count($data['currency']); 

    for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'serial' => ['required', 'unique:badges'],
        ]);
    }
```

Datos que recibo en el controllador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, que es exactamente lo que recibes en el controlado, puedes ponerlo?

Comment: Ya lo subí, necesito validar cada uno de los elementos de `serial` ya que deben ser únicos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes manejar la validación para cada elemento del array, para acceder a sus elementos debes usar `.`. En tu caso sería de la siguiente manera:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'serial'   => 'required',
    'serial.*' => 'unique:badges',
]);
```

Si no especificas el nombre de la columna dentro de la regla, el validador tomará el nombre del atributo que estás enviando, en este caso tomará los índices de tu array [0...n]. Por eso, imagino que en tu tabla debes tener un campo llamado `serial`, por lo que tu validación debe quedar así:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'serial'   => 'required',
    'serial.*' => 'unique:badges,serial',
]);
```

Comment: Me dá el siguiente error: `Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'serial.0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `badges` where `serial`.`0` = 014785201) `

Comment: Actualizada la respuesta

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre algo, en caso de que estes usando migraciones, esos campos mandarlos como unicos

```
$table->string('campo')->unique()->nullable();
```

y de esta manera al intentar registrar un 'campo' que ya esta registrado no dejara continuar el formulario.

Otra idea es hacer una consulta a tu tabla donde estes guardando
y comparar los campos que ya tienes con los del request

```
 $valores = Tabla::get();
foreach($valores as $key => $value){
if($value->code == $request->code){// tendrias que comparar por campos el code es un ejemplo
//y aqui retonas un mensaje o lo que necesites
}
 }
```

es una idea, espero ayudar en algo.
Un saludo

Comment: Muchas Gracias por responder

Comment: te sirvió de algo?

Comment: Solventé con la respuesta de L. Flor